# What is the time complexity of the following pseudocode?

Tags: function, time-complexity, big-o, pseudocode

```
XYZ(a, b, c, m, n){

For p = 1 to m do
    For q=p to n do
        c[p,q] = a[p,q] + b[p,q];}
```

I think it is n + n-1 + n-2 +.....+(n-m+1). But I am not sure. Is it this or m*n?

Comment: Hint: `1+2+3+...+N = (N+1)*N/2`

Comment: in one word - O(m*n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify your code :

```
For p from 1 to m
    For q from p to n
        Do something
```

Assuming the `Do something` part is done in constant time, what determines the time complexity of the code are the two loops. The outer loop runs `m` times, while the inner loop runs `n-p`, with p going from 1 to m.

If `m >= n`, the `Do something` part is repeated `n+(n-1)+...+1 = n*(n+1)/2 = n²/2 + n/2 = O(n²)` times.

Otherwise, if `n > m`, it's repeated `n+(n-1)+...+(n-m+1) = (n*(n+1) - (n-m)*(n-m+1))/2 = 1/2 * (n² + n - n² + 2*n*m - n - m² + m) = O(2*n*m - m²) = O(n²)` times.

In any case, `O(n²)` is a right answer, but if `n >> m`, a more precise answer is `O(n*m)`.